# Why bitwise division does not work like bitwise multiplication?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

Suppose that I want to compute `20*10=200` using only bitwise shifting. This can easily done with

```
a = 20<<3 // 2^3
b = 20<<1 // 2^1
a + b // Result is 200.
```

Now, why if I try to do the same thing for division I get a wrong result? For instance if I try to compute `200/10`

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int value = 200;
    int a = value >> 3;
    int b = value >> 1;

    printf("200/10 is %d\n", (a+b));

    return 0;
}
```

I get a `125`? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is 20 * 8 + 20 * 2 == 20 * 10?  Yes.  Is 20 / 8 + 20 / 2 == 20 / 10?

Comment: "What I'm doing wrong?" --> Wrong premise.  Cannot do division this way.

Comment: Step away from the computer and pull out the pen and paper and do the math.

Comment: Well that’s just what my teacher said. So there is no way to divide a number by another(that is not a power of 2) using right shift?

Comment: `20*8 + 20*2 = 20*(8+2) = 20*10 = 200` `200/8 + 200/2 = 200*(1/8 + 1/2) = 200*(5/8) = 125`

Comment: Ok I understood the mistake. So this means that it’s impossible to divide a number by another who is not a power of 2(such as 3)?

Comment: @beep No, it just means division isn't associative.  https://www.google.com/search?q=division+is+not+associative

Comment: Not only can you not divide via right-shifting, except by powers of two, you cannot multiply by left-shifting, except by powers of two.  Your multiplication example uses left shift *in combination with addition*, which is not the same thing.  But also, no, the algebra does not work out for division anything like it does for multiplication.

Comment: Maybe nitpicking, but if you're using bitshifting **and** addition, is it only bitshifting then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments here have done a great job explaining why this doesn't work. Here's an elaboration a bit more on why the multiplication technique does work, and why the division technique doesn't.

Let's begin with multiplication. Suppose you want to compute 200 × 10. You could compute that by evaluating 200 × (9 + 1), or 200 × (8 + 2), etc. Each of those expressions is equivalent to the original one. Using the distributive property, this means we could compute 200 × 9 + 200 × 1 to get 200 × 10, or we could compute 200 × 8 + 200 × 2 to get 200 × 10, etc.

It just so happens that multiplying by powers of two happens to be done more easily by doing bitshifts. So, for example, we could compute 200 × 10 by evaluating

```
200 x 10 = 200 x (8 + 2)
         = 200 x 8  +  200 x 2
         = (200 << 3) + (200 << 1)
```

Now, can we do this for division? Well, it is indeed true that 200 / 10 = 200 / (8 + 2), same as before. But unlike multiplication, in the case of 200 / (8 + 2), we don't have a distributive property, so we cannot rewrite

> 200 / (8 + 2)  =  (200 / 8) + (200 / 2).

Therefore, we can't use the reverse of the bitshifting technique to quickly do the division.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I assume that efficiency is not a concern here, that it is just for fun (or a homework?).

As explained already, you cannot divide by 10 with bit shifting as easily as you can multiply by 10.

However, It is quite possible to use bit shifting for such a division, except that more shiftings are necessary.

For example, we can use the fact that `1/10 = 1/8 - 1/10 (1/4)`

Output:

```
3/10 = 0
12/10 = 1
128/10 = 13
1465/10 = 147
4566/10 = 457
5674/10 = 567
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
int div10 (int n) {
    if (n == 0) return 0;
    return (n >> 3) - div10(n >> 2);
}

int main () {
    int nums[] = {3, 12, 128, 1465, 4566, 5674};
    int n = sizeof(nums)/ sizeof(nums[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int num = nums[i];
        int ans = div10(num);
        printf ("%d/10 = %d\n", num, ans);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `div10()` gives a  _somewhat_ rounded result like `div10(7) --> 0` and `div10(8) --> 1`.  `div10(negative)`  leads to stack overflow.

Comment: @chux The result is rounded effectively but why unclear? Effectively the negative case must be handled differently, always the case with right shiftings. Note that in the past, with microcontrollers with additions and shifting only, these kinds of tricks for division (filter implementation) were very usual. This is why I wanted to react versus the *it is not possible* unanimity. These tricks were also used in hardware implementation.

Comment: @chux OK, I did not see you modified your comment. Effectively the rounding is approximate. My goal here is not to replace the existing division implementation !

Answer (score 0):

You've gotten good answers, but allow me to offer another view of this that might be simpler. This was the multiplication:

```
a = 20<<3 
b = 20<<1 
a + b
```

And you wanted to do division like this:

```
a = 20>>3 
b = 20>>1 
a + b
```

The problem here is that you only have reversed the individual parts. You need to reverse the whole process. Let's take a simple example from temperatures. If you have a certain temperature `c` in Celsius and want to convert it to Fahrenheit, you do it with this formula:

```
f = 1.8c + 32
```

What you're trying is to convert back to Celsius with the same formula:

```
c = f/1.8 - 32
```

But since the addition was the last step in the original formula, we need to reverse that step **before** we reverse the multiplication. Here is the correct inversion:

```
c = (f-32)/1.8
```